# How to call the result from another method in the same Activity in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a calculator, and I faced some problems with it.
When I try to run the program, it is okay to show the first screen to let me enter the number (in the situation that I ignored the last 2 code of setText for result).
After I put the data in the Edittext fields and press the button, it is going to be stopped (Unfortunately the application has been stopped)

The code shown below is the method that will be called when I press the button after all information is filled, and I have the formula created in another method separately (the totalCost and profit variable).

I am not sure if it is the right way to assign the result from another method to the variable, and not sure why the toString() method in `setText` doesn't work (error saying that double cannot be dereferenced)

Here is the code for ref:

```
public void sendInput(View view) {
    EditText editTextPurPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_PP);
    EditText editTextSelPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_SP);
    EditText editTextStkQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_QTY);
    EditText editTextLotSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_LS);
    TextView resultTTCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTTCost);
    TextView resultProfit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultProfit);

    Double msgPurPrice = Double.parseDouble(editTextPurPrice.getText().toString());
    Double msgSelPrice = Double.parseDouble(editTextSelPrice.getText().toString());
    int msgStkQty = Integer.parseInt(editTextStkQty.getText().toString());
    int msgLotSize = Integer.parseInt(editTextLotSize.getText().toString());

    double totalCost = getTotalCost(msgPurPrice, msgSelPrice, msgStkQty, msgLotSize);
    double profit = getProfit(msgPurPrice, msgSelPrice, msgStkQty, msgLotSize);

    resultTTCost.setText(totalCost.toString());
    resultProfit.setText(profit.toString());
}
```

Hope someone could help me out...

Comment: If you have a crash, please copy paste logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultTTCost.setText(String.valueOf(totalCost));
resultProfit.setText(String.valueOf(profit));
```

You need to convert double to String. The other implemention is like this:

```
double aDouble = 0.11;
String aString = Double.toString(aDouble);
```

Comment: Appreciated! the answer is helpful and inspired. After that I also find out the reason why the toString() method doesn't work in setText in my case.

Comment: @TroyKC if it was helpful marked as correct answer then buddy !!

Answer (score 3):

Problem ia setext it should as below

```
    resultTTCost.setText(""+totalCost);
    resultProfit.setText(""+profit);
```

Or

```
  resultTTCost.setText(String.valueOf(totalCost));
  resultProfit.setText(String.valueOf
```

Comment: Empty String concatenation is regarded as bad coding style!

Comment: Appreciated! the answer is helpful and inspired